# Problems with pods in xcode

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

Project on flutter. When I try to open a project and just add new dependencies through xcode, the ide does not see them.I don’t even know where to start looking for a solution to the problem, like I’m doing everything right. Can someone help me? if any additional information can help you, please ask me to show you.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Cocoapods v1.1.1 is hopelessly outdated. Are you sure you're using that?

Answer (score 1):

Try building the project. The IDE needs to build all of the pods before it picks them up automatically. Easy mistake to overlook.